# vba sum value in column except one

Tags: vba, exception, sum, rows

I have a matrix in microsoft reports. It looks:

```
Product             | Sold 
apple               | 1000
melon               | 200
banana              | 500
orange              | 2000
sum(without orange) | x
sum                 | 3700
```

How to write expression in vba to sum all values without orange? Number of rows with fruits can be different so i cant use static index to identify product

Comment: `sumif` or `if/else` as a starting point. [edit your question to fit SO standards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=sum(IIf(Fields!Product.Value<>"orange", Fields!Sold.Value, 0))
```